# Merging [tag:patent-drawings] and [tag:drawing]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

[patent-drawings](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patent-drawings) and [drawing](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing) seem synonymous. Let's merge them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I just merged the specified tags. Not something I'm experience with so hope it works.